# headphones problem: internal speakers are working fine,but when heaphones are plugged in Iam only able to hear background sound vocals are not clear

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I have dual booted system on my dell 3537 with windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 in windows both internal speakers and headphones are fine but in Ubuntu    headphones are not working please need a help regarding that !!

Answer (score 0):

try installing Alsa sound mixer software, it lets you control the master volume as well as headphones and speaker volume configuration

you can download it from here:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-alsamixer/

Answer (score 0):

First, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-utils
```

Then, run this command:

```
alsamixer
```

Now, press <kbd>F6</kbd> and press the down arrow key  to select your sound card, press <kbd>enter</kbd> and then, press <kbd>F3</kbd>.

Next, use the  (right arrow key) to navigate to the **Auto-Mute Mode** channel and then press the  (up arrow key) to set **automute** to **disabled**.

Finally, plug in your headphones. You may notice the **Headphone** channel will be at zero or **0<>0**. This happens when you plug the headphones in and you will need to increase the volume after you plug the headphones in. Use the left  or right  arrow key  to navigate to the headphones channel and use the up arrow key  to turn up the volume. When you are finished, you can press <kbd>esc</kbd> to exit alsamixer.

Additionally, if the **Headphone** channel or any of the other channels such as Master say **MM** at the bottom of the channel, navigate to that channel and press the <kbd>M</kbd> to toggle mute off. When mute is off, the channel should say **OO** instead of **MM**.